# External hdd boot entries added to GRUB after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, 13.10

Long story short, I was using my laptop's internal HDD as an external one on my desktop, and I forgot to remove it when I was upgrading to 13.10.

Now GRUB on my desktop has added entries for the Windows and Ubuntu partitions that exist on the laptop's HDD, but I don't want them to be there. Can I safely remove them ?

My GRUB table looks like this if I recall correctly:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced Options (or something like this)
Memtest
Another Memtest Entry
Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sdb1
Ubuntu 13.04
Advanced Options for Ubuntu 13.04
```

Where

```
Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sdb1
Ubuntu 13.04
Advanced Options for Ubuntu 13.04
```

are the entries from the external/laptop's HDD.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your issue simply by removing the laptop's hard drive from your desktop (if it is still attached) and issuing the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Voila! You should now be ship shape! :)